# Date Comparison Trouble in status change PHP

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with the date comparison loop of our project. it seems like it is not reading the syntax properly. The DonationDate needs to be compared to DonationDate. '+ 90 Days'. if the DonationDate is less than or equal to DonationDate. ' + 90 Days'. the result should be replenishing but I am getting active donors even if the input date is today.

Here is the code:

````
<?php $sql = "SELECT * from  tblblooddonars WHERE status='Donated' ";
    $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
                                        
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{   
 foreach($results as $result)
 {?>    
    <tr>
    <td style="color:black;font-size:18px;"><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?> 
    </td>
    <td>
       <span style="color:black;font-size:18px;"><?php echo 
        htmlentities($result->LastName);?></span>
       <span style="color:black;font-size:18px;"><?php echo 
        htmlentities($result->FirstName);?></span>
       <span style="color:black;font-size:18px;"><?php echo 
        htmlentities($result->MiddleInitial);?></span>                                              
    </td>
    <td>
       <span style="color:black;font-size:18px;"><?php echo 
        htmlentities($result->BloodGroup);?></span>
    </td>
    <td>
       <span style="color:black;font-size:18px;"><?php echo date('M d, 
        Y',strtotime($result->Birthdate));?></span>
    </td>
    <td>
       <span style="color:black;font-size:18px;"><?php echo date('M d, 
        Y',strtotime($result->DonationDate));?></span>
    </td>
<?php
   if ($result->status=='Approve' 
       && date('M d, Y',strtotime($result->DonationDate)) <= date('M d, 
       Y',strtotime($result->DonationDate. '+ 90 Days'))
      )
     { ?>
         <td style="max-width:50px;">
            <span style="color:black;font-size:18px;"><label 
             style="color:red">Replenishing</a></span>
         </td>
    <?php 
     } else {
    ?>
        <td style="max-width:50px;">
          <span style="color:black;font- 
           size:18px;"><label style="color:green">Active Donor</a></span> 
        </td>                                           
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</tr>
    <?php 
           $cnt=$cnt+1; 
      } 
    ?>
<?php 
}?
> ```
````

Comment: You should use `date_diff` / `DateTime::diff()` rather than trying to compare two strings like that

Comment: Use only `strtotime($result->DonationDate)` and not `date('M d, Y', strtotime($result->DonationDate))` because later compares _strings_

Comment: You don't use text to do date calculations for the same reason that you don't use text to do maths (`'two' + 'three'` in PHP used to equal `0` before it was disallowed).

Comment: already tried it but it didn't work. anyway, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: What does your DonationDate look like when you request it from the database?

Comment: it is in YYYY-MM-DD in the database. but i have converted it  to M d, Y format in the data table output.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't compare date format like that.
Either you use comparable format ie YYYY-MM-DD (Y-m-d)

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime($result->DonationDate)) <= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($result->DonationDate. '+ 90 Days')))
```

Or just comparing the two strtotime()

```
strtotime($result->DonationDate) <= strtotime($result->DonationDate. '+ 90 Days')
```

Comment: I'll test it now and see if it works.

Comment: already tried it but didn't work either. anyway thank you for helping.

Comment: @DaveRiusManriquehow logic said the compared date will will always returning true because you compare the date with the addition of date. You might want to check if $result->status is really stored as 'Approve' or check the date format stored in database.

Comment: @DaveRiusManrique try var_dump($result) and show it here